# File opration cpp

Tags: c++, file

```
bool  UserDeatiles::loginUser(){
      string vEmail,vPasswd;
      UserDeatiles trm;
        ifstream fin("User.txt" , std::ios::in);
       if(!fin.is_open()){
         //throw CustomException(fin , "File could not be opened ");
         cout << "File could not be opened." << endl;
         exit(1);
      }
      cout << "Enter the valid username : ";
      cin >> vEmail;
      cout << "Enter the password : ";
      cin >> vPasswd;


      while(fin.read((char*)&trm , sizeof(trm))){
        if(vEmail.compare(trm.returnEmail()) == 0 && vPasswd.compare(trm.returnPasswd())==0){
            cout << "Wellcome " << trm.name << endl;
            fin.close();
            //trm.clear();
            return true;
        }
        //fin.read((char*)&trm , sizeof(trm));

      }

      if(fin.bad()){
            cout << "Error in file operation." << endl;
            exit(1);
      }
      cout << "Invalid Login credentials !.." << endl;
      fin.close();   
      return false;
}
```

In the above login function gives the segmentation fault after it successfully return to main function in main function here is where it `loginUser()` returns  to main

```
switch (choice){

            case 1 : loginCheck = temp.loginUser();
                     if(loginCheck){
                        cout << "you are login successfully .!";
                     }else{
                        cout << "If you don't have any account sighup " << endl;
                     }
                     break;
```

I stuck here can u please help me .

Comment: Debugging and checking the backtrace is quite useful for this kind of errors

Comment: What is `UserDeatiles`? That `fin.read` is very suspicious

Comment: UserDeatiles is a class

Comment: I tried a lot and it works fine without file operation but when file comes always giving problem

Comment: There are very strict limitations to what you can `read` like that. You probably want some kind of serialization.

Comment: @molbdnilo Thanks for your answer , I want read as Object . is there any mistake while reading .?

Comment: @RakeshSR You need a [trivial](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TrivialType) object for that. Most C++ objects are not.

Comment: @molbdnilo Thanks i'll go through it

Comment: The problem is likely coming from `UserDeatiles` I think it stores internally `std::string` which can't be read using `read`

Comment: @dev65 really thank you , My code compiled successfully ..